# How to disable Inline variables view in WebStorm 9?

Tags: debugging, webstorm

Here is what I mean by Inline variables view:

> See **variable values** next to their usages with Inline variables view, a new debugging feature that integrates the Variables view right in the editor.

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/#inline

Is it possible to disable this feature? How do I do that?